# writing arrays to csv

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am looping through 2d array (data) then populate fields using different segments of the arrays that I am looping over. Below is the sample code:

```
with open('output.csv' , 'wb') as outcsv:
    headers = ['Field1', 'Field2', 'LongField']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    for i in range(numArrays):
        row = [{'Field1': data[i][:3],
                'Field2': data[i][3:5],
                'LongField': data[i][5:]}]
        writer.writerows(row)
```

I am getting the desired output for all fields except the 'LongField' where the number of values are large (hundreds, could be even few thousands) and varying.
Here is what my output looks like:

```
Field1 Field2 LongField
3,4,5  1,2    array([0,0,0,...,0,0,0])
5,3,6  0,9    array([0,0,0,...,0,0,0])
```

Is this happening because im exceeding some kind of maximum allow values I can write to a cell? Is there a way for me to write all actual values into the cell?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: because you do not have an ending index maybe it takes the remaining of the array and outputs it like an array. Try puting `len(data[i])` like the following:  `[5:len(data[i])]`

Comment: What is some sample `data`? What do you want the data in the `LongField` column to be? How do you expect to put many values to appear in a single csv column?

Comment: @deltashade I have tried that, but the same results..

Comment: @martineau here is the output when I type data

Comment: array([[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.,], [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.,], ..., ]])

Comment: Please read [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), provide one and include example `data` _in the question_ please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect OP wants all those 0's to print, no matter how many there are. No `array(` nor `)` and no ellipsis `...`

**EDIT:**
See comment from @John:

> For anyone happening upon this in the future, `numpy.savetxt()` does what the OP wants without having to create the strings by hand.

**Guess:**

Try `','.join([str(_) for _ in data[i][5:]])`

**In full:**

```
row = [{'Field1': data[i][:3], 'Field2': data[i][3:5], 'LongField':  ','.join([str(_) for _ in data[i][5:]])}]
```

[Related to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16483149/1175496)

**Help us:**

What kind of array are you using? Can you show us more code? Or tell output of: `type(data[0])`

**EDIT**

OP clarified what kind of array and how long it is:

It's a `numpy.array` (or one dimension of the `ndarray`; same str treatment)

And it's 2,984 long.

Apparently a str version of `numpy.array` will truncate  all but first 3 and last 3 elements when the array has 1000 elements or more

999 elements:

```
str(numpy.array(range(1000)))
>>[  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
>>  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
>>  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53
>>  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71
>>  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
>>  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107
etc...
```

1000 elements:

```
str(numpy.array(range(1001)))
>>'[   0    1    2 ...,  998  999 1000]'
```

So I think my original recommendation should work, forcing it to the string representation you want. I think CSV `DictWriter` should take care of quoting.

```
','.join([str(_) for _ in numpy.array(range(2987))])
```

**EDIT**

Explaining my answer:

So you are not giving DictWriter a string -- it must infer the string. I assume DictWriter will use Python [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) function. As the documentation says, the `str` function will:

> Return a string containing a nicely printable representation of an object.

I suppose `numpy` developers thought that an `array` with >999 elements would **not** be very "printable"

So above 1000 they probably have the  `__str__` function return a "summarized" version, which only shows first 3 elements and last 3 elements.

Instead of letting DictWriter or the `str` give you a string, you can create exactly the string you want. I believe the string you want is just all the elements of the array separated by a comma, that's what this code does:

```
','.join([str(_) for _ in [1,2,3]])
```

- `','.join()` will "concatenate" all the elements on a comma; elements must be strings
- the `[str(_) for _ in [1,2,3]]` will convert the individual elements to strings (required for the join to work)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Here's the output of type(data[0]):
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: here is the output of data: >>>data
array([[0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.,], [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.,], ..., ]])

Comment: >>> len(data[0])     2984

Comment: Thanks, then I think you can join on a comma manually as described above

Comment: I still don't know why though.. could you help explain please?

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer, if my answer is acceptable can you mark it as the correct answer? (Click the checkbox next to the answer on upper-left)

Comment: Marked it. Thank you!

Comment: For anyone happening upon this in the future, numpy.savetxt() does what the OP wants without having to create the strings by hand.