# Converting string to numpy array and vice versa in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am having a `numpy` array which is the image read by open `cv` and saving it as a string. So I have converted the `np` array to string and stored the same. Now I wanted to retrieve the value(which is a string) and convert to original `numpy` array dimension. Could you all please help me in how to do that?

My code is as below:

```
img = cv2.imread('9d98.jpeg',0)
img.shape    # --> (149,115)
img_str=np.array2string(img,precision=2,separator=',') # to string length 197? which I dont know how
img_numpy=np.fromstring(img_str,dtype=np.uint8) # shape (197,) since this is returning only 1D array
```

Please help me in resolving the same

Comment: Can you give an example `img_str` ?

Comment: Look at `img_str`.  See all the ellipsis (...).  That's controlled by the `threshhold` parameter.  This is the same sort of condensation we get from a simple `print(img)`.  It also includes all the nested []  of a normal print.  It's not a good format for saving.

Comment: Where do you intend to 'save' this string?  A file?  Since it's a 2d array, you could use the `csv` format produced by `savetxt`, and loaded by `loadtxt`.

Comment: There's also a `np.fromstring(img.tostring(),int)` round trip, though that looses shape information.  And the non string `np.save/np.load` option.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj.. sorry for the delay. The image numpy array needs to be converted to string to push it to cloud. To access from cloud, I need to get it from cloud and re convert it again to numpy array

Answer (score 2):

The challenge is to save not only the data buffer, but also the shape and dtype.  `np.fromstring` reads the data buffer, but as a 1d array; you have to get the dtype and shape from else where.

```
In [184]: a=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [185]: np.fromstring(a.tostring(),int)
Out[185]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])

In [186]: np.fromstring(a.tostring(),a.dtype).reshape(a.shape)
Out[186]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Is going to json an option?

Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16483494/8069403):

```
import numpy as np
import json

img = np.ones((10, 20))
img_str = json.dumps(img.tolist())
img_numpy = numpy.array(json.loads(img_str))
```